# Do you know any independent keyword (phrase) statistics trend website?

Tags: seo, keywords, search, statistics

Does anyone know an equally impressive service that shows the amount of times a specific keyword (phrase) has been searched, as well as a branch of other similar words?

The one discussed in this video (Wordtracker.com) seems very good, but has gone commercial unfortunately which is not what I'm looking for. I really would prefer free tool.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H2M1tXtAc18&feature=related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Adwords Keyword Tool](https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/Explorer?__u=1000000000&__c=1000000000&ideaRequestType=KEYWORD_IDEAS#search.none) and [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends) will probably do what you need.